# bxSlider - Remove Numbers from Pager?

Tags: jquery, css, html, bxslider

I'm using bxSlider from here: http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-pager and I have it working fine, but i want bullets to be used instead of the numbers so I added this to the css file:

```
    .bx-pager a{
  background: transparent url('/src/images/bullets.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding: 0 4px;
}
.bx-pager a.pager-active{
  background-position: 0 -58px;
}
```

It works fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the images.. so I'm left with this: http://cl.ly/223N0h251T0T251S2U2T

any ideas?

Comment: can you please share this slider on jsfiddle.net? after that it can be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
.bx-pager a{
  background: transparent url('/src/images/bullets.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: transparent;
  }
.bx-pager a.pager-active{
  background-position: 0 -58px;
  color: transparent;

  }
```

Change is here  `color: transparent;`

Comment: this removes the numbers, but the bullets aren't clickable.. how do I make them work without the numbers?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way:

```
.bx-pager a {
  background: transparent url('/src/images/bullets.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding: 0 4px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  }
.bx-pager a.pager-active{
  background-position: 0 -58px;
  }
```